# Select recursive data with cascade option in Oracle tables

Tags: java, database, oracle

I am looking for something similar to `ON DELETE CASCADE` while selecting the rows.

When I select parent table entity which defines dependency on child elements, I want them to be loaded automatically (and recursively).

Otherwise, I will have to put extra effort to perform the same (by creating dependency graph and traversing that to find the relation).

Sample Classes:

```
Class A{
private Long id;
private Member1 member1;
private Member2 member2;
@Join
private B b;

}

Class B{
private Long id;
private Member1 member1;
private Member2 member2;
@Join
private C b;
}

Class C{
private Long id;
private Member1 member1;
private Member2 member2;
}
```

While loading class A (i.e Table A), I want it to fetch corresponding data from class B and C (i.e Table B and C) as well.

I am using Carbonado along with Java.

Comment: You can use hibernate. It provides this functionality by default (although for collections you need to specify fetch type eager explicitly)

Comment: I am using Carbonado along with Java. Even for Hibernate, I guess it needs to be defined in advance. I don't want this to happen in all the cases, I only want for some set of queries.